# Windows Server 2003 SP2 - What version of LDAP am I using?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ldap

Is it possible to check the LDAP version in Windows Server 2003 without running a powershell script?

Thanks,
Toast

Comment: Do you mean what version of LDAP your Active Directory installation is using?

Comment: Absolutely, forgive me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following vbscript will work :

```
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

For Each strVersion In objRootDSE.Get("SupportedLDAPVersion")
  Wscript.Echo "LDAP Version: " & strVersion 
Next
```

returns :

LDAP Version: 3

LDAP Version: 2

see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/89ac522b-d21e-4b2c-ba28-0b3cd7c96b9d

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent help, just a little note:  The 'Next' at the very end belongs to a new line, otherwise the script returns a punch to the kidney.  Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, AD's LDAP supports the LDAPv3 protocol uniformly.

Comment: I believe that is a well known fact.